# Exporting Data from Layer Export introducing slivers in coincident data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, slivers

I am seeing odd behaviour in Arcmap 10.6 where I select a layer and export its data and then choose to import the exported data and when it comes in I see slivers in areas which are coincident in the source data.

Coordinate system is the same as source when exported.  Below are images of the resulting output data and the original source data zoomed to the same scale.  Seems to happen on curved borders.

[[image: resulting output data[1]]

[image: source data]

How can I keep from introducing slivers into the data when I export the layer?

Comment: Try [Integrate tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm). It may solve the problem.

Comment: This are true curves, not supported in shapefiles. I have impression it can happen between 2 databases as well due to different xy resolution or some other mysterious things. Never happens between shapefiles.

Comment: I'd saved attributes in point fc , centroid inside, add geometry attributes. Unbuild to polylines, dissolve. Features to polygon, transfer attributes. Expect slightly changed geometries, hopefully slivers free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapefiles not supporting true curves seems to be the issue, if I export the data to another geodatabase the slivers are not introduced.  Thanks FelixIP!